# Delay handling hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseevent

I want a certain text top up when I hover over an image on my website. It all works well the only problem I have is that I want to have the hover triggered only when the cursor is on the image for 1second so the site doesnt get all bouncy and stuff. Problem is i cant manage to make it work.
Here is a simple version of it in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwAdG/14/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li ><a href="#">Header 1 &darr;</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">content</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    #nav {
    padding: 40px;
    border: solid #999 1px;
}
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#nav ul li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 40px;
}
#nav a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;

}
#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JS:

```
   var config = {  
      timeout: 1500,
     over: function () { //onMouseOver callback 
        $('ul', this).slideDown(500);//show its submenu

    },    
    timeout: 1500, // milliseconds delay before onMouseOut   
    out: function () { // function = onMouseOut callback 
        $('ul', this).slideUp(1500); //hide its submenu        
    }     
};
$('#nav li').hoverIntent(config);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hoverIntent plugin that you're using has a method called interval.
I'd consider using that instead.

```
interval: 1000,
timeout: 500 // milliseconds delay before onMouseOut
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xwAdG/16/)

From the docs:

> interval:
>   The number of milliseconds hoverIntent waits between reading/comparing mouse coordinates. When the user's mouse first enters the element its coordinates are recorded. The soonest the "over" function can be called is after a single polling interval. Setting the polling interval higher will increase the delay before the first possible "over" call, but also increases the time to the next point of comparison. Default interval: 100

Comment: Well this one works exactly how i needed it THANKS :D

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.hoverDelay.js](http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/) is a jQuery plugin that does exactly that. It enables you to set a delayed hover effect (you can set a different delays for the "in" and "out" callbacks).
And best of all, I Wrote It :-)

Check the demo here: http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/

**JS Usage**

```
$('#demo-menu li').hoverDelay({
    delayIn: 200,
    delayOut:700,
    handlerIn: function($element){
        $element.css({backgroundColor: 'red'});  
    },
    handlerOut: function($element){
        $element.css({backgroundColor: 'auto'});  
    }
});
```

Comment: The demo doesnt show delay on the event it instantly triggers it or is it just in the demo?\

Comment: In the demo the 'delayIn' parameter is set to 200ms, so maybe it looks almost instantly, but you can see that if you move your mouse over the list, without stopping, the "hoverIn" callback never gets executed.